# what is a replacement for the else if?

Tags: c++

so many people told me that using a lot of (else if) in my code is not good practice and it is a bad design but i do not know how can i improve it or change it so for example how can i improve this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
int vowels[5];
int count;
int main() {
    std::string name;
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)
    {
        if (name[i] == 'a') {
            vowels[0]++;
            count++;
        }
        else if (name[i] == 'e') {
            vowels[1]++;
            count++;
        }
        else if (name[i] == 'i') {
            vowels[2]++;
            count++;
        }
        else if (name[i] == 'o') {
            vowels[3]++;
            count++;
        }
        else if (name[i] == 'u') {
            vowels[4]++;
            count++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "The number of vowels in this name is : " << count << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel a : " << vowels[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel e : " << vowels[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel i : " << vowels[2] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel o : " << vowels[3] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel u : " << vowels[4] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, [`switch-case`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-statement-cc/) is a replacement for `if - else if` in many cases.

Comment: @JeJo It has been -- it is a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `switch` statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)
{
    switch (name[i]) {
        case 'a':
        vowels[0]++;
        count++;
        break;
    case 'e':
        vowels[1]++;
        count++;
        break;
    case 'i':
        vowels[2]++;
        count++;
        break;
    case 'o':
        vowels[3]++;
        count++;
        break;
    case 'u':
        vowels[4]++;
        count++;
        break;
    }
}
```

or an `std::map` with loops:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<char, int> vowels = {
            {'a', 0},
            {'e', 0},
            {'i', 0},
            {'o', 0},
            {'u', 0}
    };

    std::string word = "the quick brown fox";

    for (const char c : word) {
        auto v = vowels.find(c);
        if (v != vowels.end()) {
            v->second += 1;
        }
    }

    auto count = 0;
    for (const auto& [key, value] : vowels) {
        count += value;
    }

    std::cout << "vowel count: " << count;
}
```

or an `std::map` with `<algorithm>` and `<numeric>`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::map<char, int> vowels = {
            {'a', 0},
            {'e', 0},
            {'i', 0},
            {'o', 0},
            {'u', 0}
    };

    std::string word = "the quick brown fox";

    std::for_each(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), [&vowels](const char c) {
        auto iter = vowels.find(c);
        if (iter != vowels.end()) {
            iter->second++;
        }
    });

    auto count = std::accumulate(vowels.cbegin(), vowels.cend(), 0,
            [](const int acc, const auto& kv) {
        return acc + kv.second;
    });

    std::cout << count;
}
```

Comment: A `std::map` is quite an overkill for this.

Comment: @Acorn that's why it was not the first suggestion :)

Comment: I would expect the performance of the map version an order of magnitude worse than the switch. For that reason I wouldn't even offer it as a solution.

Comment: @rustyx While I agree with you that given a real world problem solvable by such a simple `switch`, the `std::map` approach would be undesirable due to performance differences. However, I believe that OP is a beginner who could benefit from simple introducion to `std::map` given a somewhat familiar example. I am maybe not the best person (and using not the best tool) to introduce such concepts, but nonetheless - this is an approach to a problem, which variances may be as well solved by using `std::map`.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular example, you can use a `switch` instead, since `char` is a numeric type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int vowels[5] = {};
int count = 0;

int main() {
    std::string name;
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    for (char ch : name)
    {
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'a': {
                vowels[0]++;
                ++count;
                break;
            }
            case 'e': {
                vowels[1]++;
                ++count;
                break;
            }
            case 'i': {
                vowels[2]++;
                ++count;
                break;
            }
            case 'o': {
                vowels[3]++;
                ++count;
                break;
            }
            case 'u': {
                vowels[4]++;
                ++count;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "The number of vowels in this name is : " << count << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel a : " << vowels[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel e : " << vowels[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel i : " << vowels[2] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel o : " << vowels[3] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel u : " << vowels[4] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You can simplify it further by using a `std::map` to track the counts:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<char, int> vowels;
int count = 0;

int main() {
    std::string name;
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    for (char ch : name)
    {
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u': {
                vowels[ch]++;
                ++count;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "The number of vowels in this name is : " << count << "\n";
    for(auto &vowel : vowels)
        std::cout << "The number of the vowel " << vowel.first << ": " << vowel.second << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to perform the search and then [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to get the index:

```
constexpr char vowelNames[] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

for (const auto c : name) {
    const auto it = std::find(
        std::begin(vowelNames),
        std::end(vowelNames),
        c
    );

    if (it != std::end(vowelNames)) {
        ++vowels[std::distance(std::begin(vowelNames), it)];
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be a `switch`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)
{
    ++count;
    switch (name[i]) {
        case 'a':
            vowels[0]++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            vowels[1]++;
            break;
        case 'i':
            vowels[2]++;
            break;
        case 'o':
            vowels[3]++;
            break;
        case 'u':
            vowels[4]++;
            break;
        default:
            --count;
            break;
    }
}
```

Another alternative - if you just want to count occurances of characters would be to use a map:

```
std::map<char, int> counts;
for (const char c : name) {
    counts[c]++;
}
```

Then, to know the count of any char, just look it up:

```
std::cout << "The number of 'e's in the string: " << counts['e'] << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for your specific case using [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string name;
    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    // Waiting range library
    auto count = [](const std::string& s, char c) { return std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), c); };
    const int vowels[] = {
        count(name, 'a'),
        count(name, 'e'),
        count(name, 'i'),
        count(name, 'o'),
        count(name, 'u')
    };
    const auto total = std::accumulate(std::begin(vowels), std::end(vowels), 0);
    std::cout << "The number of vowels in this name is : " << total << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel a : " << vowels[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel e : " << vowels[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel i : " << vowels[2] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel o : " << vowels[3] << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of the vowel u : " << vowels[4] << "\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Y8kHH1)